# Order of deletion and contraction to form a minor

Tags: graph-theory

I have been reading a couple of sites regarding minors and have come across the statement that the order of deletion and contraction of edges do not matter. Why is that the case?

In fact, I came up with an example and am convinced that without additional hypotheses, this cannot be true. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Consider $G=K_4$ with one edge missing. Then we have 2 vertices of degree 3 and 2 vertices of degree 2. Let $x$ be a vertex of degree 3 and y be a vertex of degree 2 and $x,y$ are adjacent. After contracting $xy$, we get $K_3$ and after deleting an edge, we get a path of length 2 (number of edges). However, if we were to first delete the edge and then do a contraction, we will end up with $K_3$.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the order of deletions and contractions not matter you must allow for multigraphs. In your case, allowing for parallel edges and loops, contracting $xy$ first results in $K_3$ with an additional edge in parallel to one of the other edges. You cannot discard that edge.

Comment: Do you mean to say that in the first case, if I want to end up with a path of length 2, I then have to do 2 deletions on these edges, which will be the same as doing two deletions and then a contraction?

Comment: @HaikalYeo Yes, that's exactly right.